# Sphinx search or MySQL for a huge database search enginee

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

So I'm working on a huge eCommerce solution on top of Symfony2, Doctrine2 and MySQL (maybe a cluster since we will have a lot of people connected and working in our platform) so I'm trying to decide if will be better to use Sphinx search or MysQL for search solution since some data will need to be duplicated in MySQL tables and in Sphinx. Our main goal is performance so excellent response times is what we look for. I'm not an expert in none so I need some advice from people here based on theirs experience and so on, maybe some docs or whatever. What path did yours take on this side.

PS: The DB will grow up really fast take that into account and the platform will be for the entire worl

Comment: Its obligatory to view this: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql - looks like here too, but need to signup http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-08-22-full-text-search-throwdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx is usually preferred when it comes to performance vs MySQL for high volume searches because it's easy to scale. You will have a delay on results, to allow it to sync data with mysql, but even so it's better.

You should also take a good look at the actual queries that will run and store in Sphinx
only the fields that are searchable along with their ids. Once you get the ids from sphinx, 
to list them use a mysql slave to get their other, non-searchable data.

Depending on what queries you are using for search,

A better solution than sphinx is [Amazon Cloudsearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/). We had a hard time implementing it, but it was well worth it, both time and $$$, and it replaced our sphinx solution

Comment: Sphinx does have real-time indexes, so can avoid batch-building the indexes - with the inherient delay. And if performance is important, can use attributes, so sphinx returns the data (avoiding the need to go to the databse)

Comment: Indeed, but depends a lot of exactly what is being done on the tables... A huge rate of write operations, especially the DELETES, made us forget about rt indexes on sphinx :(